# Application of Rouché's (Rouche's) Theorem to a Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Here is my question:

> State Rouché's theorem. How many roots of the polynomial $p(z) = z^8 + 3 z^7 + 6 z^2 + 1$ are contained in the annulus {$1 < |z| < 2$}?

The statement is fine.

I then consider the functions $g_1 (z) = z^8 + 3z^7 + 1$ and $f_1(z) = 6z^2$, giving one root of $p = f_1 + g_1$ inside {$|z| < 1$}, as $f_1(z) = 0 \iff z=0$.

I then consider the functions $g_2(z) = z^8 + 6z^2 + 1$ and $f_2(z) = 3z^7$, giving one root of $p = f_2 + g_2$ inside {$|z| < 2$}, as $f_2(z) = 0 \iff z=0$.

Thus I have no roots inside {$1<|z|<2$}.

Is this correct? It's a past exam question, so I'm surprised that there would be *no* roots inside the given annulus...

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're forgetting about multiplicity. For example, in $B(0, 1)$, $6z^2$ has two zeroes (counted with multiplicity), so $p$ has two zeroes (counted with multiplicity) in $B(0, 1)$.

Also, once you've determined how many zeroes $p$ has in $B(0, 1)$ and $B(0, 2)$, then you know how many zeroes it has in $B(0, 2)\setminus B(0, 1) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 \leq |z| < 2\}$. You should then explain why none of those zeroes lie on $S^1$.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks. I was thinking about multiplicity, but for some reason I had in my head that 0 was always single multiplicity!?!

Comment: Could you consider $|z| = 1 + \epsilon$, $\epsilon << 1$, and then show that $|f_1(z)| > |g_1(z)|$ in {$|z| < 1 + \epsilon$} as we have, on $|z| = 1$, $f_1(z) = 6 > 5 \ge |g_1(z)|$, and there is a non-zero gap (that is, not just a strict inequality to the same value, eg $x < 2 \le y$). This says that $p$ still has two roots inside {$|z| < 1 + \epsilon$}.